# Using HttpClient 4.x instead of the build-in pre-beta

Tags: android, httpclient

Is there a way to use in my android project newer version of `HttpClient`?

I've tried to import + set in build path newer `HttpClient` jars, my app is compiled without errors in Eclipse but when I run it in a emulator or real device it produces force close because obviously at runtime the app is referencing the build-in library not the 4.1.1...
I've read somewhere that there is a way to "repackage" at built time using `Maven` but I don't have a clue where to start. I will appreciate any directions that may lead me to using 4.1.1 instead of the built-in version.

To give some context: I am trying to port to android existing legacy code which depends on 4.1 features, i.e. I am trying to avoid major rewriting of my old code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not strictly possible. You do not control the classloader, and the firmware always wins.

You could use [`jarjar`](http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/) or something to refactor 4.1.1 into a new package (e.g., `ogre.apache.httpclient`) that does not conflict with Android's, then change up all your imports to use that package.